# Using reflection to load values from XML into a structure

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, reflection

I'm using Reflection to load some values from an XML into a structure. All works but I got a problem to manage the array. With an Int32 it's ok, but how can I manage an Int32[]?

EDIT: Here's my code ... it's not complete due the lenght ... I want to improve the save and load for the array types.

```
    //My struct ... it should be a class too
    
    public struct stOptions
    {
        public int IntNumber;
        public double DoubleNumber;
        public string String;
        public Point aPoint;
    }

    //How my class works
    
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stOptions options = new stOptions();
        //Populate the struct  
        options.aPoint = new Point(12, 24);
        options.DoubleNumber = 34d;
        options.IntNumber = 17;
        options.String = "Hello";

        ManageSettings ms = new ManageSettings();

        ms.SaveSettings("e:\\test001.xml", options);

        options = default(stOptions);

        options = ms.LoadSettings<stOptions>("e:\\test001.xml");
    }

    //A portion of my class

    public T LoadSettings<T>(string FileName)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        var returnObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        List<Settings> list = null;

        try
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(FileName))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Settings>));
                list = (List<Settings>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //Error accessing the file
            _errors.Add("Unable to locate the file or access denied: " + FileName);
            return default(T);
        }

        try
        {
            foreach (Settings entry in list)
            {
                FieldInfo field = returnObject.GetType().GetField(entry.Key.ToString());
                if (field != null)
                {
                    SetField(field, entry.Value.ToString(), returnObject);
                }
                field = null;

                PropertyInfo prop = returnObject.GetType().GetProperty(entry.Key.ToString());
                if (prop != null)
                {
                    SetField(prop, entry.Value.ToString(), returnObject);
                }
                prop = null;
            }
            list = null;
        }
        catch
        {
            //Error processing the XML
            _errors.Add("Errore processing the XML file: " + FileName);
            return default(T);
        }
        return (T)returnObject;
    }
    
    private void SetField(FieldInfo prop, string value, object returnObject)
    {
        switch (prop.FieldType.Name.ToLower())
        {
            case "uint16":
                prop.SetValue(returnObject, Convert.ToUInt16(value));
                break;

            case "uint32":
                prop.SetValue(returnObject, Convert.ToUInt32(value));
                break;
                
            etc.
            [...]
            
            default:
                //An unmanaged type
                Debug.WriteLine("Found an unmanaged type: " + prop.FieldType.Name);
                break;
        }
    }
```

When it is completed I will publish it.

Comment: Why don't you read the xml file and automatically translate it to a C# class? Like seeing in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/controlling-xml-serialization-using-attributes

Comment: Bruno, your solution is nice and works at 90%. When I'm trying to serialize a Font It fails 'cause it doesn't have a constructor without parameters. And when I'm trying to serialize a Color variable no value is written in the XML file.

Comment: Hi, could you provide a code sample of what you are doing? Perhaps editing your post with the newer code?

Comment: My goal is to create a simple structure or class with some public field and/or public properties then save it and reload it. I'm going to create a list from the object (a structure or a class) passed to my function then I'm going to serialize it.
Then I'll reload all the data using the reflection. I can send all my code but are many lines of code ... can I?
I'm new as user ... sorry and thank you for the patience.

Comment: You don't need to use reflection to retrieve the values from the XML, I am giving you a full working code sample below. I hope it gives you a good direction.

Comment: I think I didn’t understand your question correctly, let’s see if someone else can help.

Comment: Your code should work if you do not convert values to String: `field.SetValue(returnObject, entry.Value);`

Comment: Ty Uranus, but it doesn't work. Take a look at the code (now it's almost complete). Ty man.